# Perl only executes part of shell command and emits warning 'redundant argument in printf' in command substitution

Tags: perl

The following has been tested with perl 5.24 on OS X 10.11.5.

I wrote a short program (`perl-embed.pl`) to determine whether perl escapes shell metacharacters when interpolating strings into backticks (it doesn't).

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $bar = '" ; echo 45 ; "';

printf "%s\n", `echo "hi${bar}ls"`;
```

I was very surprised to see that this generated a warning and only executed part of the command.

```
$ perl perl-embed.pl
Redundant argument in printf at perl-embed.pl line 6.
hi
```

For comparison the following program (`perl-embed2.pl`) with `print` instead of `printf` runs without warnings.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $bar = '" ; echo 45 ; "';

print `echo "hi${bar}ls"`;
```

I then ran it.

```
$ perl perl-embed2.pl
hi
45
<contents of current working directory>
```

`perl-embed.pl`'s behavior is totally unexpected. `printf` interpolates the contents of strings just fine in other contexts, even if the string contains weird characters.

```
$ perl -Mstrict -Mwarnings -e 'printf "%s\n", q[5]'
5

$ perl -Mstrict -Mwarnings -e 'printf "%s\n", q["]'
"
```

The system perl (version 5.18) does not emit this warning, but seems not to execute `ls` or echo `45` like we would expect

```
$ /usr/bin/perl perl-embed.pl
hi

$ /usr/bin/perl perl-embed2.pl
hi
45
<contents of current directory>
```

Why is perl behaving this way? Note that in every case perl is exiting normally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using backticks in list context, so the expression

```
`echo "hi${bar}ls`
```

will run the command

```
 `echo "hi"; echo 45; ls`
```

and return each line of output in a separate element, for example

```
( "hi",
  "45",
  "foo",
  ...     # other files in current directory
 )
```

But the template in `printf` (`"%s\n"`) only has one placeholder, so `printf` gets confused and issues the warning, just as if you said

```
perl -we 'printf "%d\n", 1, 2, 3, 4'
```

Comment: Oh I see. ``printf "%s\n", (scalar `echo "hi"; echo 45; ls`);`` would actually have the intended behavior.